# how to get data from child user

Tags: php, sql, function, tree

I'm making a program where each user has a parent user (user tree). Every parent user can view all data held by the child user.
This time, to see all the existing data on a child user I use a script like this:

```
    $query = "select * from com_oportunity where asign_to='$lcode' ";
    $gsql=mysql_query("select a.id, b.code from com_roles a, com_users b where   a.parent_id='$lrole' and a.id=b.role");
    while($grow=mysql_fetch_row($gsql)){
        $query.=" or  asign_to='".$grow[1]."' ";
            $checksql=mysql_query("select a.id, b.code from com_roles a, com_users b where a.parent_id='$grow[0]' and a.id=b.role");
            $checksqlnum=mysql_num_rows($checksql);
            if($checksqlnum!=0){
            while($checkrow=mysql_fetch_row($checksql)){
            $query.=" or  asign_to='".$checkrow[1]."' ";
                $checksql2=mysql_query("select a.id, b.code from com_roles a, com_users b where a.parent_id='$checkrow[0]' and a.id=b.role");
                $checksqlnum2=mysql_num_rows($checksql2);
                if($checksqlnum2!=0){
                while($checkrow2=mysql_fetch_row($checksql2)){
                $query.=" or  asign_to='".$checkrow2[1]."' ";
                }
                }
            }
            }
    }
$query.=" order by id";

$sql=mysql_query($query);
```

The script is limited to a depth of 3 levels of users; if I want to have an unlimited depth levels of user, how do I simplify the script above?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to utilize the [*JOIN*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) clause (Note: the link is to the MySQL reference but most other database engines support JOIN as well - e.g. MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc).

Also notice in the sample below that I updated the [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) and similar functions to use mysqli_* functions instead... per the documentation:

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

e.g.

```
$sqlText = "SELECT DISTINCT o.* FROM com_oportunity o JOIN com_users u on o.asign_to = u.code JOIN com_roles r on (r.id = u.role OR r.parent_id = u.role) order by o.id";
//replace these values with the values you need
$server = 'server_name_or_address_here';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'passwordForUsername';
$database = 'databaseName';
$connection =    mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$database);

$updatedQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT o.* 
    FROM com_oportunity o 
    JOIN com_users u on o.asign_to = u.code 
    JOIN com_roles r on (r.id = u.role OR r.parent_id = u.role)
    order by o.id"; 
$sql=mysqli_query($connection, $updatedQuery);
if ($sql && mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($sql)){
        echo 'row: '.print_r($row,1).'<br />';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'query returned false: '.$sql.'|<br/>';
}
```